# Logistic regression with {-1,1} labels in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement logistic regression with Tensorflow. I assume that I have the labels in the form of {-1, 1}. So, I have implemented the decision function and loss function

```
def cross_entropy(y_pred, y_true):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.log(1 + tf.math.exp(- y_true * y_pred[:, 0] ))) + tf.nn.l2_loss(W)`

def logistic_regression(x):
  return tf.matmul(x, W) + b
```

Is this correct? The loss is `nan`.

Comment: Tensorflow is overkill for logistic regression. I'd suggest something like sklearn. Perhaps I'm not understanding your question, are you actually using neural networks and you want to use a response variable with values between -1 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

This is an option,

```
def logistic_regression(x):
    # Apply softmax to normalize the logits to a probability distribution.
    return tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

def cross_entropy(y_pred, y_true):

    # Encode label to a one hot vector.
    y_true = tf.one_hot(y_true, depth=num_classes)
    # Clip prediction values to avoid log(0) error.
    y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, 1e-9, 1.)

    # Compute cross-entropy.
    return tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_true * tf.math.log(y_pred)))
```

Take a look at this full implementation
https://builtin.com/data-science/guide-logistic-regression-tensorflow-20